# When this loop runs, the final array only accounts for the last run, not the whole amount. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, for-loop

I am building an array that keeps track of every 2 number pair from 1-80 over the course of a number of draws. I track the draw number as well as the frequency that the pair comes up. When I run the loop, it seems to have only tracked the results for the most recent draw, not the larger list. How can I get this to update as it goes through the loop?

I am brand new to Javascript. I have been learning it for only one week. Most of what I have learned has been from searching what I want to do any copy and pasting.

```
  var myarray = new Array()
  var final = {
    draws: new Array(),
    fq: 0
  }
    for (f=1;f<=80;f++){
      for (s=1;s<=80;s++){
          if (f < s){
            if (results.Picks[(f-1)].includes(f)){
              if (results.Picks[(f-1)].includes(s)){
                final.draws.push(results.Num[(f-1)])
                final.fq++
                myarray.push(final)
              }
              else {
                myarray.push(final)
              }
            }
            else {
              myarray.push(final)
            }
            final = {
              draws: new Array(),
              fq: 0
            }
          }
      }
    }
  console.log(myarray)
```

What I'm looking for is a way to track every number pairing over a set number of draws but I only seem to be getting the results for the most recent draw.
The Expected Output is an myarray (containing 3160 entries, one for each pair of numbers from 1-80) and in each entry for myarray (for each number pair) there should be a list of draw numbers in which it occurs as well as a frequency of occurances as a single integer for how many times it occured in the last amount of draws.

I tried adding a loop at the beginning to run the whole loop as many times as draws I have, but I don't really know how to add the values of the resulting arrays together. I end up with 100 arrays, each 3160 entries in length. I want one array that combines all those numbers.

```
//loop beginning
  var combine=new Array();
  for (i=0;i<results.Num.length;i++){

//loop ending
  combine.push(myarray)
  }
console.log(combine)
```

Comment: can you give a simple example of expected output

Comment: I've added an example by description but I can't copy/paste from the web console

Comment: If I understand correcty, what you've to do is to pre-fill `myarray`with 3160 value of `{
    draws: new Array(),
    fq: 0
  }` and then, update content of this array. something like `const f = myarray[f*80 + s]; f.draws.push(.push(results.Num[(f-1)]); f.fq+=1`

Comment: Hi Ryan and welcome to Stackoverflow. As its written, your question hides a few important details - many variables are undefined and there's probably more guessing needed to make it work than to fix it. Could you edit your question to include a complete example? As suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Ryan *"...I can't copy/paste from the web console"* That's irrelevant,  we need an example of an input of arbitrary numbers and then an example of the result *if the function actually worked* and an example of what you actually get.

Comment: Okay, I've included the complete code to give you a better idea of what its doing

Comment: ATM the site is under maintenance...I'll check latter.

Comment: The pairs are just derived in the "if" statements. f is the first number and s is the second, so if the first number is less than the second number, and the draw contains both of those numbers, then it updates the array. The pairs are every combination of numbers in groups of 2 from 1-80, so 1 & 2, 1 & 3 ... 1 & 79, 1 & 80, 2 & 3, 2 & 4 ... and so on until 78 & 79, 79 & 80.

Comment: There are 3160 possible combinations of 2 numbers from 1-80, so in the array, 0 corresponds to 1 & 2, 1 corresponds to 1 & 3, 2 corresponds to 1 & 4, etc